Formula for Mirror Numbers
Hey so I stumbled upon a Problem and I cant really find a good Solution.
The Problem is about Mirror Numbers and the Original Question was: Find a Formula to convert a number „ab“, where a and b are the digits of this number($ab = 15, a = 1, b = 5$) to its Mirror number „ba“.
My Solution was:
$ab - ba = 9\times n$; and $n = a-b$
So therefore $ab - 9\times (a-b) = ba$.
I wanted to take this Problem a step further and wanted a Solution for 3 digit number „abc“ -> „cba“
My Solution for this was:
$abc - cba = 9\times n$; and $n = 10\times (a-c)-(c-a)$
Therefore: $abc - 9\times(10\times(a-c)-(c-a)) = cba$
Now I am struggling with a Solution for 4 digit Numbers..
I already found some Kind of formula but its Not working well.
For Number 1234 the formula is $1234 - 9\times(100\times(1-4) - 10\times(2+3-(3-2)) - (4-1))$
But it doesn't work for 4321 or 1235.
Does Anyone know good resources on this topic or can someone help me find a Solution?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I think your 2-digit number approach can still work for 4-digit numbers, but you need to be careful with the algebra. Here is an attempt, maybe it can be streamlined somewhat.
$abcd=1000a+100b+10c+d$ and the mirror number is $dcba=1000d+100c+10b+a$
Let $n=abcd$ and $m=dcba$.
Then $n-m=999a+90b-90c-999d$
Which gives $m=n+999d+90c-90b-999a$ which can be written $m=n+999(d-a)+90(c-b)$
So if $n=4321$ we have $m=4321+999\times(1-4)+90\times(2-3)=4321-3\times 999-90=1234$
Generalising this to 5 digit numbers (or higher) would presumably show some sort of pattern, but with an odd number of digits, the middle digit remains the same so will not feature in the formula.

For a general definition,
If $n$= number of digits, your original number is $x$,and the $k^{th}$ digit from front can be expressed as $a_k$, then
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^{n} 10^{n-k}a_k= 10^{n-1}a_1+10^{n-2}a_2+...10a_{n-1}+a_n$$
Let $y$ be the mirror number.
$$y=\sum_{k=1}^{n} 10^{n-k}a_{n-k+1}=10^{n-1}a_{n}+10^{n-2}a_{n-1}+....10a_2+a_1$$
Thus $$x-y=\sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{n-k}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{n-k}a_{n-k+1}$$
$$=(10^{n-1}a_1+10^{n-2}a_2+...10a_{n-1}+a_n)-(10^{n-1}a_{n}+10^{n-2}a_{n-1}+....10a_2+a_1)$$
$$=a_1(10^{n-1}-1)+a_2(10^{n-2}-10)+a_3(10^{n-3}-100)+....a_{n-1}(10-10^{n-2})+a_n(1-10^n)$$
This can be expressed in the form of a single summation formula, as
$$x-y=\sum_{k=1}^{n} [10^{n-k}-10^{k-1}]a_k$$
Thus for any $x$, whose digits can be represented by $a_k$,
$$y=x-\sum_{k=1}^{n} [10^{n-k}-10^{k-1}]a_k$$
Examples:-
If $x=91$, then $n=2$, so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2} [10^{2-k}-10^{k-1}]a_k=[10^{2-1}-10^{1-1}]×9 + [10^{2-2}-10^{2-1}]×1=81-9=72$$
So $y=x-72=91-72=19$.
For $x=4321$, if you want to find a general formula for 4 digits,you need to put the desired $k$ values, and  you'll get $$x-y=999a_1+90a_2-90a_3-999a_4$$
You'll get $y=1234$ after solving it.
